# Most of my text suddenly has a line through

Tags: css, wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap

On my website: https://simplebyte.co/ some text has a line through it and when on mobile most of it is striked. It's not a CSS issue since i checked the styling and tried to apply `text-decoration: none;

What I've noticed is that text that has no styling applied in CSS is striked.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 There's no code issue, not that I noticed anyway. By editing it i just notice the issue described on refresh. I am aware of stackoverflow rules.

Comment: Yeah, there's a code issue. Most likely a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if you have a [`s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s) tag in your code (line 142):

```
</div>

            <s

        </div>
```

This will render text with a strikethrough.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter, please explain how this is wrong?